# Yii2 JUI datepicker removes HTML attribute from input field

Tags: php, yii2, jquery-ui-datepicker, yii2-basic-app

I have a yii2 ActiveForm field with a HTML5 "form" attribute like this:

```
$form->field($model, 'event_date', [
    'inputOptions' => ['form' => 'starterWizard__form']
])->label('Enter date:');
```

If I apply a jQueryUI datepicker to this field in yii2 like below, the "form" attribute no longer gets inserted on input field.

```
$form->field($model, 'event_date', [
    'inputOptions' => ['form' => 'starterWizard__form']
])->label('Enter date:')->widget(\yii\jui\DatePicker::class, ['dateFormat' => 'yyyy-MM-dd']);
```

Any idea why the widget removes "form" attribute from input field and how I can fix the issue?

Comment: Solution: https://forum.yiiframework.com/t/jui-datepicker-removes-html-attribute-from-input-field/128225

Answer (score 0):

When using widget to render a dynamic tag, it's moved away from the form and is only accessible in the controller via the $_POST[] array,

you will have to use

```
$model->attributes
```

and before that check :

```
isset($_POST['ModelName'])
```